# Django generic view not receiving an object (template issue?)

Tags: django, django-templates

My model:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    player_email = models.CharField(max_length=50)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.player_name
```

My root `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^kroster/', include('djangosite.kroster.urls')),
    (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),
)
```

My kroster `urls.py`:

```
from djangosite.kroster.models import Player

info_dict = {
    'queryset': Player.objects.all(),
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list', info_dict),
    (r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail', info_dict),
)
```

My `player_list.html` template:

```
<h1>Player List</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
<ul>
    {% for player in object.player_set.all %}
        <li id="{{ player.id }}">{{ forloop.counter }} .)&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ player }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Sadly my template output is this.

```
<h1>Player List</h1>
<ul>

</ul>
```

Apologies if this is a stupid mistake. There has to be something wrong with my template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template should be something like this:

```
<h1>Player List</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
<ul>
    {% for player in object_list %}
        <li id="{{ player.id }}">{{ forloop.counter }} .)&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ player }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Not only does it work, but it simplifies a few misunderstandings i had.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The variable for list view (unless otherwise specified) is `object_list`.

For details, it's `object`. Also, you'll need another template for the detail view. By default the template name is: `<app_label>/<model_name>_detail.html` (unless you specify it differently)

All is in *[Generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/)*.